# Should I use a plural noun when grouping two cancers? “Pancreatic and prostate cancer(s)”

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

My girlfriend (non-native speaker) recently approached me with the following question - which of the following would you use?

- Glycemic variants affect pancreatic and prostate cancer, but not colorectal and breast cancer.
- Glycemic variants affect pancreatic and prostate cancers, but not colorectal and breast cancers.

As a native speaker I felt like both were appropriate - in the first, you're implying the missing 'cancer' after pancreatic - the expanded form would be "pancreatic cancer and prostate cancer".

In the second, you're grouping them together and saying (pancreatic and prostate) cancers.

Does this analysis make sense? Which of the two would be a preferred or more common usage? The context is academic writing, if that makes a difference.

Comment: If you're talking about only a single thing, then it's singular, but if you're talking about the *combination* of two single things, then it's plural. So, if I have **pancreatic cancer** *and* I also have **prostate cancer**, then what I have is **two cancers**, and the plural needed. The singular would only make sense if you had a *single* type of cancer than affected both your pancreas and your prostate at the same time.

Comment: Your final example is very misleading, not only because it uses **or** instead of **and**, but also because there isn't any confusion in the first place. In the first version, the recipe doesn't require a ***single*** carrot, but several carrots, regardless of their colour. So, even if a conjunction were not used, it would be a plural noun. In the second version, you've changed the sentence so (again using **or**), it's referring to one single thing or another single thing, which makes the singular required.

Comment: @JasonBassford good point, I was trying to show the thinking and work I'd done already but it did just end up making the question more complex entirely! I've removed that section.

Comment: @JasonBassford And that first comment clears things up a lot. I now see the difference. Could you post it as an answer? Thank you.

Comment: Cancer is both countable and uncountable. Technically there are many types of cancer but all have an underlying similarity but a different expression. As a generic term, cancer is uncountable: “Cancer kills 66% of people.” “Lung cancer has increased.” If there is a distinction between the type (rather than the site) of cancer, cancer is countable: “Cancers of the lung include small cell and squamous cell cancers and mesothelioma .” See https://www.foundationmedicine.com/blog/uncovering-insights-in-pancreatic-and-prostate-cancers for the plural use. I would suggest the plural given the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [dictionary confirms](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cancer) that *cancer* has a plural, *cancers*. It also confirms that cancer is a *variable noun*, so it can be countable or uncountable.

As cancers grow, a cancer is singular no matter how large it is or how far it spreads. Clinicans refer to *multiple cancer sites* when someone has different kinds of cancers, but everyday speech you might say someone has *multiple cancers*.

However, your example is a little different, and functions like a *list*:

> Glycemic variants affect **pancreatic and prostate cancer**, but not **colorectal and breast cancer**.

When you make a list of multiple types of something, you can end on a singular noun, for example:

> We sell strawberry, chocolate, and vanilla ice-cream.

This is essentially the same as saying:

> We sell strawberry ice-cream, chocolate ice-cream, and vanilla ice-cream.

You *could* pluralise 'ice-creams' if you wanted to refer to each one sold, but ice-cream can be a uncountable noun so it works either way.

Likewise, your example is fine as it is - you could say "pancreatic cancer and prostate cancer", so you can also say "pancreatic and prostate cancer". Or "cancers", either is fine.

Comment: This is fantastic. The ice-cream example really helps. It's good to know my mental 'sounds-alright-o-meter' was working alright, but it's even more helpful to have a clear explanation for why this is the case. I've now learned about variable nouns! Thank you.